# Are there any reStructuredText to HTML parser(or library, perhaps?) written in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, restructuredtext

I have an Android app which should be able to display reStructuredText as HTML inside WebView. It already has support for few other markups using javascript libraries. As far as I know, there is no javascript implementation of reStructuredText yet. Most online tools uses `docutils` or similar as backend but I'd like to do the conversion on client side.

[reStructuredText tool support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746692/restructuredtext-tool-support) lists a lot of tools and two of them, [JRst](http://maven-site.nuiton.org/jrst/en/index.html) (Java) and [Laika](http://planet42.github.io/Laika/) (Scala), might do the trick on Android.

However, for making maintenance easier, I'm still looking for a javascript library which converts reStructuredText to HTML.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746692/restructuredtext-tool-support

Comment: @Mikhail I know that listing. It has been linked in my question from the beginnng

Comment: Did you ever find anything? It seems that even in 2022, there's still a lack of available options for parsing RST in JS