# Reading Django documentation with restview

Tags: django, python-2.7, restructuredtext, docutils

I am using Fedora 18 on Virtual Box on my Windows XP desktop to learn Django. After going through the `.txt` documentation files, I discovered these files were written using restructuredText. I've been spending the last day or so trying to figure out how to convert the files into something readable (HTML, Latex, PDF, etc.). First thing I did, was install docutils (from [source](http://sourceforge.net/projects/docutils/files/docutils/0.11/docutils-0.11.tar.gz/download?use_mirror=softlayer-dal&download=) - download page) and used `rst2html.py` to convert the files to HTML to be readable.

When I used this tool, I was getting the `Unknown interpreted text role "doc"`, `Unknown interpreted text role "ref"`, `Unknown interpreted text role "term"` errors, and more when opening the `docs/intro/index.txt`, `docs/intro/install.txt` and `docs/intro/tutorial01.txt` files. I was able to find very little on Google describing the exact problem I was having so I tried to use a different option.

Naively thinking the errors were native to docutils I decided to search for another tool and found [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746692/restructuredtext-tool-support) and installed restview. Well, I didn't realize restview used docutils so I ended up back at square one.

How do I get rid of these and other errors? Did I install docutils and restview correctly?

Please tell me if I need to add more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/index.html). This tool [is used by the Django project](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-documentation/#getting-started-with-sphinx) and it defines additional reStructuredText constructs to complement those defined by docutils. Such as

- http://sphinx-doc.org/markup/inline.html#role-doc
- http://sphinx-doc.org/markup/inline.html#role-ref
- http://sphinx-doc.org/markup/inline.html#role-term

Comment: I will have to look more into it. I already installed it but thought it was only for producing documentation. I guess it makes sense I can read ReST with it

Comment: I looked at the link you posted to the Django project and it told me exactly what to do. Unfortunately, I received another error, but I'm moving in the right direction. Thanks